# Parse a schedule table with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to parse items from a schedule, having their day and time stored inside the item. Imagine the week view in a calendar:

```
     | Mon    | Tue    | Wed    | Thr    |
------------------------------------------
8am  | Event1 | Event2 |        | Event3 |
9am  |        | Event4 | Event5 |        |
10am |        |        |        |        |
11am | Event6 |        |        |        |
```

The ideal item would look like:

```py
{
    'name': 'Event4',
    'day': 'Tue',
    'time': '9am',
}
```

The HTML structure is the usual table structure with `<tr>` and `<td>` (and `<th>` for the header). Note: The table could also be pretty sparse.

My best idea is to take advantage of the fixed number of columns, then iterate by row, manually list column by column `.css('td:nth-child(1)')` etc. Which is very ugly, and since I'm new to Scrapy really feels like I'm doing it wrong.

What's the sane solution to this?

Comment: Your "very ugly" idea is right. There is no other magic way to process above HTML.

Comment: Can I at least get the ordinal number of the `td` I just scraped? The `n` in `nth-child` so I can deduce which column header it's under?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get column headers:

```
headers = response.xpath('//table//th/text()').getall()
```

And next iterate each row:

```
for row in response.xpath('//table//tr[position() > 1]'):
    index = 0
    for td_value in row.xpath('./td/text()').getall():
        column_name = headers[index]
        index += 1
```

Comment: `xpath('//table//tr[position() > 1]')` is there a way to make that `position()` return to me that number straight from the selector? Like an attribute.

Comment: You can use XPath's `count()` to count preceding `tr` but why do you need it?